# How to copy directory from remote server

Tags: linux, rsync, remote-access, scp

I came across following instruction to copy a directory to my local machine.

```
copy the gems from styx server from "‪location/to/the/directory" to your local directory
```

I know rsync and scp can do the job, but to do that a username on the remote machine is required. How can I work around without a username or can I?

Comment: You need a user I think

Comment: FTP sometimes allows anonymous access.  We need more information about the server you're connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

The full tutorial is [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html)

Copy file from a remote server to a local computer

```
rsync -v -e ssh jerry@openbsd.nixcraft.in:~/webroot.txt /tmp
```

you can use [ssh authentication,](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=238672) you won't need password, but always a user, you can create another user for security reasons